# Flutter - Get checkbox feedback when modifying in another class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

*Guys, I created some checkboxes in another class to avoid the refrash when I modify them, but I can't get the check back. Can someone help me?
I will leave the code below ..*

**on my main page, I call the class containing the checkboxes like this ..**

I tried every possible way and I can't get the checkbox value on my main page

```
**//here I call the click event on my main page**
TipoPagamento(
onChanged: (v) {
  setState(() {
   print(v);
  });
  }
),

//**this is where i set up my checkbox.**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TipoPagamento extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TipoPagamentoState createState() => _TipoPagamentoState();
  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;
  const TipoPagamento({Key key,@required this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);
}
class _TipoPagamentoState extends State<TipoPagamento> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  int _radioValue = 0;
  @override
   _handleRadioValueChange(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue = value;
      switch (_radioValue) {
        case 1:
          break;
        case 2:
          break;
        case 3:
          break;
      }
    });
    return(_radioValue);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildTextField();
  }
  Widget buildTextField() {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        new Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: _radioValue,
          onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
        ),
        new Text(
          'Débito',
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
        new Radio(
          value: 2,
          groupValue: _radioValue,
          onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
        ),
        new Text(
          'Crédito',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
        new Radio(
          value: 3,
          groupValue: _radioValue,
          onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
        ),
        new Text(
          'Dinheiro',
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can call `widget.onChanged(_radioValue);` in `_handleRadioValueChange` 
code snippet

```
_handleRadioValueChange(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue = value;
      switch (_radioValue) {
        case 1:
          break;
        case 2:
          break;
        case 3:
          break;
      }
    });

    widget.onChanged(_radioValue);
    return (_radioValue);
  }
```

working demo

[image]

output of working demo

```
I/flutter ( 6880): v 1
I/flutter ( 6880): v 2
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TipoPagamento extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TipoPagamentoState createState() => _TipoPagamentoState();
  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;
  const TipoPagamento({Key key, @required this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);
}

class _TipoPagamentoState extends State<TipoPagamento> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  int _radioValue = 0;

  _handleRadioValueChange(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue = value;
      switch (_radioValue) {
        case 1:
          break;
        case 2:
          break;
        case 3:
          break;
      }
    });

    widget.onChanged(_radioValue);
    return (_radioValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildTextField();
  }

  Widget buildTextField() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: _radioValue,
          onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
        ),
        Text(
          'Débito',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
        Radio(
          value: 2,
          groupValue: _radioValue,
          onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
        ),
        Text(
          'Crédito',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
        Radio(
          value: 3,
          groupValue: _radioValue,
          onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
        ),
        Text(
          'Dinheiro',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TipoPagamento(onChanged: (v) {
              setState(() {
                print("v $v");
              });
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, now i can get the return. however when I modify the checkbox it ends up reloading. how do I avoid this?

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. Need to reproduce your modified code. could you post your modified reproduce code to a new question? thanks.

Comment: so as not to update I removed it from setstat inside my main page                TipoPagamento(onChanged: (v) {
                    idTipoPagamento = v;
                  }),